# How much does broadcast receiver cost for memory?

Tags: android, memory, broadcastreceiver

*Scope:* Have to update activity UI in different ways. Update depends on broadcasts received from service.
*Problem:* There are two common ways to find out which way UI should be updated:

1. register only 1 broadcast receiver but put different extras in its intent and check for them in OnReceive() method in activity;
2. register broadcasts for each update command.

The 2nd ways seems to be more elegant and more understandable. But I wonder if it will consume more memory. What would you recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with CommonsWare. From a perfomance standpoing this isn't really something you need to worry about. That said, I'd probably go with 2nd way for the sole reason that it will make your code more modular thus improving maintainability.

Comment: Totally agree! Thanks, no more doubts about it.

Answer (score 4):

It should not make a major difference either way.